# How to get previous target of click using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to get previous target on click using jquery?
Because I need to compare the previous element that was clicked and compare it to the current element that I currently clicked.

Something like this:

```
$('#myTab').on('click', function(e){
var prevTar = e.target.prev();

if(prevTar == e.target){
console.log('view all');
}
})
```

Comment: `e.target` is trippy. `e.target` is more than less not the element you think you're targeting. Also this is most likely an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - you're asking about X without explaining Y but actually Z might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Store the previous target into an external variable

```js
let prevTar;

$('#myTab').on('click', function(evt) {
  const target = evt.target
  if (prevTar === target) {
    console.log('view all');
  }
  // Update prev target
  prevTar = target;
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myTab">
  <li>Lorem <span>SPANIPSUM</span></li>
  <li>Dolor <b>bold amet</b></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see above, the `e.target` might not always reflect the expected LI Element (if i.e: the Event originates in a LI descendant). To tackle that problem you could use Event delegation like:

```js
let prevTar;

$('#myTab').on('click', "li", function(evt) {

  if (prevTar === this) {
    console.log('view all');
  }
  // Update prev target
  prevTar = this;
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myTab">
  <li>Lorem <span>SPANIPSUM</span></li>
  <li>Dolor <b>bold amet</b></li>
</ul>
```

Now, even if you click on a descendant (`<i>` or `<span>`) of a `<li>` Element the code will work as expected since the `this` will reference the handler LI from the delegator `#myTab` UL element.

For completeness, the JavaScript counterpart of the above code would be:

```js
let prevTar;

document.querySelector("#myTab").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const target = evt.target.closest("li");
  
  if (prevTar === target) {
    console.log('view all');
  }
  // Update prev target
  prevTar = target;
  
});
```

```html
<ul id="myTab">
  <li>Lorem <span>SPANIPSUM</span></li>
  <li>Dolor <b>bold amet</b></li>
</ul>
```